# Docker Compose with Volumes in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-compose, containers

After reading the several options for running containers in Google Cloud, I still cannot find a proper solution among the myriad of options - Cloud Run, Kubernetes, Container-OS...

We need to be able to:

- run a docker image (hosted in dockerhub)
- mount a persistent disk as a volume. Big data files will be stored there.
- expose ports to the internet
- automatic scalability (to 0 when not in use, for example, at night)

Answer (score 1):

Focusing **only** on `GCP` environment as in the question.

There are solutions that could be used to run workloads as you described. Some of them are:

- Kubernetes Engine
- Cloud Run

You can read more about the differences between `GKE` and `Cloud Run` here:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Blog: Products: Containers Kubernetes: When to use Google Kubernetes Engine vs Cloud Run for containers](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/when-to-use-google-kubernetes-engine-vs-cloud-run-for-containers)*

---

You could use *[GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine)* for your workload as for the bullet points you mentioned:

> - run a docker image (hosted in dockerhub)

Kubernetes uses Docker images. You have an option to specify the place the images are being downloaded *[from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999146/how-do-i-authenticate-gke-to-my-third-party-private-docker-registry)*.

---

> - mount a persistent disk as a volume. Big data files will be stored there.

By default `GKE` uses `gce-pd` as the backbone for `PVC`'s and `PV`'s. You will be able to store data needed for pods there:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Persistent Volumes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes)*

---

> - expose ports to the internet

Kubernetes has a wide variety of options to allow the traffic to enter your cluster. Some of them are:

- `ClusterIP` - internal only
- `NodePort`
- `LoadBalancer`
- `Ingress`

You can read more about them here:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: How to: Exposing apps](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps)*

---

> - automatic scalability (to 0 when not in use, for example, at night)

By using Kubernetes you can automatically scale not only nodes but also pods that are running your application:

- [Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Cluster Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) - cluster autoscaler will **not** scale down to 0 nodes automatically
- Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (amount of replicas):

  - *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Horizontal Pod Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/horizontalpodautoscaler)* - HPA will **not** scale to 0 pods
- Vertical Pod Autoscaler (resources and limit):

  - *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/verticalpodautoscaler)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials)*
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Kompose](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose)* - Translate Docker Compose to Kubernetes